# Questions on isomorphisms and bijectivity

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the difference between an isomorphism and a linear bijective transformation?

Also, Bijectivity $\Rightarrow$ Invertibility or Bijectivity $\iff$ Invertibility?

Also, does $T\circ S$=$S\circ T$ imply that $T$ and $S$ are both bijective and that $T=S^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a categorical point of view, an isomorphism is an invertible morphism. In many categories (but not all) for which a morphism can be interpreted as a particular *map* between *sets*, an isomorphism is but a bijective morphism. This is the case for the category of vector spaces over a field, and more generally of $R$-modules over a field.

For your second question, the answer is no: $T\circ0=0\circ T=0$ is a counter-example.

Comment: To stress the second sentence: There are categories where we cannot say that the objects are "just" sets with some additional structure and morphisms are just maps between these sets that respect the structure. But even if a category has this property (is a so-called concrete category), it need not be the case that a morphism whose underlying set-map is bijective is an isomorphism. Example: The category **Top** of topological spaces; if a continuous map is bijective, its inverse map need not be continuous.

Answer (score 1):

A bijective linear map is an isomorphism between vector spaces. The term isomorphism is very general and can be formulated in category theory. Without going into any detail, an isomorphism of groups for example is a bijective grouphomomorphism. The word isomorphism originates from Greek. 'Iso' means 'the same' and 'morph' means 'form' or 'shape'. Hence an isomorphism between two structures basically says that they are the same.

As for your last question, no $S\circ T=T\circ S$ simply means that $S$ and $T$ commute. If however you meant that $S\circ T=Id=T\circ S$, then the answer is yes.